# Get all posts that was created after a specific post

Tags: wordpress

I couldn’t find anything in the web regarding this question.
Is there any way to use `WP_Query` (or something similar) to get all posts that was created **after** a specific post (giving a post id, for example)?

Im asking this because I need to build an application that send each month a mail with a report of the last month Woocommece’s orders, and it should be very accurate.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's say our first post is called `foo`. You just have to query `foo` and get the posted/published date back. Then, run another query and use [date_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) with the `after` key within `wp_query`. Use the returned date from earlier, from `foo` as the `date_query` `after` value. That will return all posts from after `foo` post/publish date

Comment: @ProEvilz But what if a post published two seconds after `foo`? I want to get it either, but the minimal unit for `after` is days

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `after` can get also a Unix timestap, so I end up with this code:

```
$post_date = get_the_date('H-i-s-m-d-Y', $last_post_id);
$units = explode('-', $post_date);
$timestamp = mktime($units[0], $units[1], $units[2], $units[3], $units[4], $units[5]);

$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('c', $timestamp)
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

And it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First run a query to find the reference post you need and get the published date. If you cannot use "after" parameter because of the units limitation and you want to be as accurate as possible, use a custom query with $wpdb like this:

```
 <?php

 $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date > datepost
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 ?>
```

More info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query